# Windows 7 - How to make hidden files count when it comes to hard disk space?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

I have noticed that hidden files do not count when I hover the mouse to see information on directory size, however hidden files get counted when I click on folder's "Properties".

How do I make hidden files count when I hover my mouse over a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

There's only one setting within Explorer that controls if hidden files should be shown:
[image: Folder options]

But the mouse over display happily ignores them. However, it actually reads all files (*file2* is set to hidden in this folder) so it seems it filters any hidden file:

[image: File operations by mouse over handler]

I'm assuming this comes from the fact that a "normal" user shouldn't be bothered with system files that are set to hidden, e.g. desktop.ini.